# fetch from JSON url

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch, key-value

I am a noob at javascript and I am trying to figure out how to fetch JSON data from a url and organize it into a visual representation in respect to the month. Here is the question:

Data: https://api.goodwillwa.org/stores?group_level=3

```
{
    key: [
    year,
    month,
    day
    ],

    value: [
    totalTransactions,
    totalSales,
    totalDiscounts,
    totalItemsSold
    ]
}
```

**Objective: Using client-side javascript fetch the json data and create a visualization of
the data by month. You may use any libraries you find useful. Extra points for brevity.**

I am putting everything into a webpage and attempting to write it out on the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html)
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Code Test</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 id="title">This is the month</h1>
        <script>
            function codeTest(key, value)
            {
            // code will fetch the json data structure and disply it in the html document


            }

        </script>
        <p id="new"></p>
        <button type="button" onclick="codeTest()"> Display information</button>
    </body> 
</html>
```

I am trying to make it appear blank until a button is pushed which will cause it to display on the screen. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: What have you tried? So far you've got an empty function, have written any code to try to load from the remote URL?

Comment: var url = "https://api.goodwillwa.org/stores?group_level=3";
    $.getJSON(url, function(data){
    alert(data);
});
I am very new to this language. I havent even begun thinking about how to format it in a document. Im just trying to figure out how to even retrieve the information.

Answer (score 0):

in your onclick attribute you assign a call to codeTest() but the arguments are blank (aka nothing inside the parentheses) when your definition of codeTest expects a key and value aka codeTest(key,value).

From what I understand you would want codeTest to take no arguments and look like this:

```
function codetest(){
    $.ajax({
        url:your url in "string" format,
        dataType:"json"
        "success":function(resp){
             // resp is an object
             // so you do resp.key to get the associated value
             // so assign the data you get in resp to variables you have in your webpage JS
             // then assign your HTML values to the JS variables
        }
    });
}
```

Your URL should serve you the *stringified* version of the JSON data.

You might want to reformat your data to:

```
{
    //key:value
    "year":"2014",
    "month":"march",
    "day":"27",
    "totalTransactions":"alot",
    "totalSales":"starbucks level",
    "totalDiscounts":"none hehe",
    "totalItemsSold":"alot alot"

}
```

This is one JSON 'object' of data... if you have more then you need an array of these objects and a slightly different approach. Let me know - Niko hth

Comment: Please note this is a jquery solution

Comment: oh right, then OP consider pasting this into your HTML before your original <script> tags: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">

Comment: Thank you for the help. Im just not getting it. maybe not cut out for this stuff lol.